# Can I remove the app name prefix from a custom module added by an app?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

Is there a way to remove the app name prefix from a module name added via an app manifest?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siVs6.png)

It's pretty much unreadable like this.

Answer (score 1):

That's a known issue. It's currently not possible to remove.
https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-20741